# Why does pgf calculate arc sine incorrectly (by a lot)?

Tags: calculations, pgfmath, floating-point

Reasonable imprecision is OK, but diverging from a calculator by entire 10 degrees is unacceptable.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath
  { \angle=sin(9.00000/9.48683)^-1;
  } % should be 71.56445
\begin{document}
  \angle % 60.38649
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says 60.3978 (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28%289.00000%2F9.48683%29*pi%2F180%29%5E-1), as for the LaTeX3 FPU. Where do you get 71.56445 from?

Comment: `asin(9.00000/9.48683)` is 71.56462, and `sin(9.00000/9.48683)^-1` (or `1/sin(9.00000/9.48683)`) is 60.38649. `asin(x)` is not the same as `sin(x)^-1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calculators often denote the *arc sin* function as `sin-1` (probably because it's more compact to write on the button) because *arc sin* is the inverse of *sin* (that is, one computes an angle given the sine, the other computes the sine given an angle).

However *arc sin(x)* is **not** equal to *sin(x)<sup>-1</sup>*. It's easy to see that if you take a more extreme angle. [*arc sin(0)*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin%280%29) is zero (note that WolframAlpha transcribes the input `arcsin(0)` to `sin-1(0)`, which should not be confused with `sin(0)-1`), however [*sin(0)<sup>-1</sup>*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%280%29%5E-1) gives a slightly larger result ;-)

`sin-1(x)` denotes the *inverse* sine of *x*, where the superscript *-1* is *not* an exponent. Whereas `sin(x)-1` is the *reciprocal* of *sin(x)*, in which case the *-1* is an exponent, which means `1/sin(x)` (see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30317/arcsin-written-as-sin-1x) and Crowley's comment below this answer). However very few systems understand the `sin-1(x)` notation (probably Wolfram and one or two more), because it's tricky to teach a parser that a `^-1` after `sin` means a completely different thing than a `^2` in the very same place. Add that to the usual difficulty of programming anything in TeX and you see why this doesn't work.

If you use the proper notation, `pgfmath` computes both correctly:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath { \anglea=sin(9.00000/9.48683)^-1; }
\tikzmath { \angleb=asin(9.00000/9.48683); }
\begin{document}
  \anglea % 60.38649
  \space
  \angleb % 71.56462
\end{document}
```

so does `xfp` ;-)

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
  \fpeval{sind(9.00000/9.48683)^-1} % 60.39779524788624
  \space
  \fpeval{asind(9.00000/9.48683)} % 71.56510517950239
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the LaTeX3 FPU, I'd use `sind` and `asind` as the conversion between degrees and radians is tricky

Comment: I wish I can add +1/0 for the "slightly larger result" note. You owe me cleaning the screen for that.

Comment: I"d add the source of the confusion. The inverse functions are often denoted with -1 index. `f^-1(f(x)) = x`. With this notation, the arcus sinus may be denoted as `sin^-1(x)`. On the other hand, the denominators are also written as nominators powered by -1. Therefore `1/sin(x)` is transcripted as `sin(x)^-1` which is, to be more precise `(sin(x))^-1`.

Comment: @Crowley Thanks for the explanation. I added a paragraph to the answer